# Missing features in Ckeditor

Tags: yii2, yii-extensions, yii-components

Using yii2-ckeditor-widget but missing upload tab and browser, how can I integrate those features .. 
I have tried the 2amigos CKEditor Widget for editor.

But cant upload the image though I paste the url of the image.
any solution to get those features in yii2 ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to define your Upload Action:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'content')->widget(CKEditor::className(), [
        'options' => ['rows' => 6],
        'preset' => 'basic'
        'clientOptions' => [
            'filebrowserUploadUrl' => 'site/url'
        ]
    ]) ?>
```

And there should be your handler for file uploads on this route (http://hosannahighertech.co.tz/blog/mweledi/11-Yii2-CKEditor-and-Images-Upload).

You also can use file manager plugin which have integration with ckeditor:

https://github.com/MihailDev/yii2-elfinder

https://github.com/MihailDev/yii2-ckeditor